# Eclipse Mars m2e not using Maven mirrorOf * settings.xml correctly during bootstrap

Tags: eclipse, maven

A Maven mirrorOf * setting is not helping me when I do not yet have my corporate pom in my local Repository.  A repository entry in settings.xml does work, though.  Is the mirrorOf * failure expected behavior, or is it a bug?

For example, given an empty local repository and this settings.xml file that supposedly redirects everything to ourcorporate repository (which has our corporate pom in it):

```
<settings>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>bootstrap-repository</id>
            <name>Bootstrap Repository</name>
            <url>http://myinternalhost/path</url>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
</settings>
```

And given a project pom that declares the corporate pom as its parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycorp</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-corporate-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-DNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

I get this error in Eclipse when invoking Maven on the project:

```
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\me\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.mycorp:my-corporate-pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\me\.m2\repository)
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.mycorp:myproj:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mycorp:my-corporate-pom:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 10
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.mycorp:myproj:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mycorp:my-corporate-pom:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 10

at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:422)
at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:419)
at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:83)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

However, invoking Maven succeeds -- the corporate pom is discovered, downloaded to the local respository, and used as the parent for my project -- when I change my settings.xml file to include the repository directly, like this:

```
<settings>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>!skip-corp-repository</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>corp-download-repository</id>
                    <name>Corporate Download Repository</name>
                    <url>http://myinternalhost/path</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

Is the failure with mirrorOf * expected behavior, or is it a bug?